# USB internet (airtel - Huawei E392) dongle not detected after upgrade to 12.10

Tags: usb

I upgraded the ubuntu on my laptop from 12.04 -> 12.10. In 12.04, I followed the installation procedure for linux. Whenever i connect the USB dongle, the application launches on detection and I can connect using the GUI window.

I upgraded to ubuntu 12.10, when I am connecting the dongle. The device is not detected.

After this i tried the usb_modeswitch method, adding the rule in the /lib/udev/rules/40-usb_modeswitch** with the vendor and devid. I can see in the "dmesg" the modem detection as:

```
[ 2111.508851] usb 2-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 16 using ehci_hcd
[ 2111.609813] usb 2-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 2111.610163] usb 2-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
[ 2111.610476] usb 2-1.4: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB2
```

I created a connection in the network_configuration and re-connected the USB dongle, but still connection is not activating in the Network Manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to establish connection (for both 3/4G) using the wvdial. Answering this, using the connection made by the device which raised this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the connection manually. In **Network Connections** click <kbd>Add</kbd>, choose **Mobile Broadband**. Does the usb device show up in **Create a connection for this mobile broadband device**?

If yes - simply follow the steps to create the connection.

Comment: thanks for replying Frost, no the device is **not coming** in the **create connection** window. Couldn't get why so.